# Are there ley lines in Bangladesh?

Tags: local-knowledge, bangladesh

Does any one know of [ley lines](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ley_line) (or major/minor vortices) in Bangladesh ? Especially near Dhaka ? Even around the Indian Bangladesh border should be alright.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ley lines by definition are just alignment of objects or natural elements in a fortuitous line.  They are a classic example of apophenia; seeing meaningful patterns or connections in random or meaningless data.

So yes, there 'are' ley lines in Bangladesh, you just have to find some natural items which are in a convenient line, and thus, you have your ley line.

As for famous ones, no, the primary 'research' into ley lines was very much done in Britain in the 20th century and has since faded.  There's no scientific basis for such lines forming - it's purely by chance, and indeed, [since 1989, refutations of Watkins' ideas have been generally based on mathematical methods such as statistics and Shape Analysis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ley_line#Criticism).

Comment: Fantastic. Any places you know which are associated with spiritual and mystical theories about alignments of land forms ?